# Best Choice for Storing Chat History in Langchain

Tags: python, nlp, langchain, large-language-model, llama

I've been actively working with Langchain for some time now and have experimented with various memory types within the framework. Currently, I'm using the [ConversationalBufferMemory](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/multiple_memory) with [SQLChatMessageHistory](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/memory/sql_chat_message_history), which utilizes SQLite as the database backend to store chat history.

As I'm planning to move my project into production, I'm contemplating whether it's the best practice to stick with SQLite or if there are better alternatives available, such as migrating to PostgreSQL.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, best practices, or personal experiences you can share regarding the choice of database for storing chat history in Langchain. Are there any other database options that are well-suited for this use case within Langchain that I should consider?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: it depends on the use case, if the usage traffic would be high then you should go with other options like MongoDb or Milvus etc.  Also you can think of storing these history as vector stores (if you want to hold all history of users)

Comment: How can I separate each user's chat if I use the Vector store? 
Will the LLM figure out this Manually or do we need to provide an index or something?

Comment: u can separate each user's using metadata, that is available.

Comment: You can create a vector db table for user history and this table will have user's email address or user id etc. When users logs in fetch all history or recent history based on user's email address. Alternatively, you can create metadata against each user record and its history, you can then fetch all history or recent  history based on meta data parameter. Vector db's like Mongo Db , Milvus or any other db have support for metadata.

Comment: @ZKS Sorry, I'm a newbie! Why should we use the Vector store to store all chat history of users? what is main different btw using the Vector store and normal MongoDb for chat history?

Comment: @spirit If you have unstructured datas like sentences, pdf, videos, image, etc, you can use vector DB, but if you have structured data like key,value pairs, relations, etc use Normal DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late to the party, but wanted to share a solution since there were no answers here. AWS's DynamoDB is a NoSQL database which works perfectly for storing conversational history at scale and integrates with LangChain's `ConversationalBufferHistory`. Here are the reasons I suggest this over the solutions you proposed above:

- It's extremely inexpensive, especially in comparison to a PostGRES solution. The biggest cost for DynamoDB is storage, however if your application doesn't have many users, you'll likely fall within the free tier (25gb/month are free). With PostGRES you will pay for the cost of storage and compute hours. Those compute hours really add up, especially during development when your application isn't generating revenue... and considering an enterprise solution where you'll have separate databases for dev, QA, prod, and others which multiply compute costs... while having multiple DynamoDB tables for these environments is free
- It has the benefit of persistence over SQLite. With SQLite, persistence will have to be managed manually: i.e. copying the SQLite file off your container or server every time you destroy it. Little jobs like this cause stress for engineers and are prone to human error
- DynamoDB is built for scale; it's durable and highly available and by leveraging it you'll never have to worry about it being overwhelmed by a growing user base
- This data access pattern is what NoSQL databases are designed for!
- The comments above mention using a vector store, but this is not the best-practice use of a vector store. Vector stores provide data to an LLM in order to help it answer questions... using this for chat history will result in a loss in control over how the LLM is presented with chat history

Use user IDs to definite which histories a use has access to and session IDs which can be used to retrieve and reactivate a session. Happy coding!

Comment: Note that questions asking for product recommendations are categorically off-topic here, and per the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), questions that are "not about programming [as defined in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (a definition that includes the no-product-recommendation-requests limitation) are best closed unanswered.

Comment: LangChain is a library that provides multi-language support for programmatically interacting with LLMs. The question asks about managing conversation history, which is a fundamental part of building LLM-based applications. If this isn't programming, I better change my job title :)

Comment: The list in which requests for library/tool/product recommendations are found is for things that are off-topic despite _otherwise_ being about programming. (I work in this space -- I'm familiar with langchain, and and have a product that splits between FAISS and Pinecone as the two vectorstore backends. I agree that it's programming, but that doesn't make it on-topic "as defined in the Help Center").

Comment: Yes, Langchain is a viable library but... this is one of *many* possible solutions. For every framework, you could argue that there would be a separate answer. And your answer is effectively a product pitch, talking about pricing, benefits, scale, etc. And product pitches can easily be flagged as spam. Also, most of your answer is opinion-based (another reason why "use product/service *x*" is not a valid answer)